# List entire file list

Tags: onedrive, live-sdk

I need to retrieve the whole OneDrive file list of the user, to sync it to my local database.

Is there a good solution?

I don't want to recursively traverse the whole file tree, which is very inefficient...

At first I thought I could do it with the /search&q=* endpoint, but they return max 500 results with no pagination option.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately recursion is the only way you can accomplish this at the moment. Hopefully this is something that will be improved in the future.

Comment: I'd like to request that this be a priority for the team.  Not only does Dropbox and Google Drive both provide an interface to do this efficiently, I'm seeing the MS servers throttle my app when I'm traversing the directory too fast.